# How to get nginx to handle https for keycloak

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I'm trying to get Keycloak `3.4.3.Final` docker container to work. I'm able to load the container over http, and i'm immediately shown an https required message.

So i've setup a proxy-pass using nginx with the following configuration

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    upstream keycloak-stream {
        server keycloak:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name  localhost redacted.com *.redacted.com;
        autoindex off;

        location / {
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_pass https://keycloak-stream;

            proxy_set_header Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        }

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate     /run/secrets/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /run/secrets/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam        /run/secrets/dhparam.pem;
    }
}
```

I've set the following env:

`PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`

I seem to be getting the following error:

`nginx_1     | 2018/03/27 21:48:30 [error] 7#7: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.1.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.1.0.3:8080/auth/", host: "localhost.redacted.com"`

What do i need to modify to get keycloak to accept https connection from nginx?

Comment: Do you have NGINX and Keycloak both installed in the same server? If yes, then you might be interested in removing the HTTPS requirement for keycloak itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus on the actual error:

```
ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

That means there is a mismatch in versions in client/server SSL records.
So e.g. a client sends a SSL2 client_hello handshake 
message and the counterpart is configured only for SSL3/TLS1.